# Binding values of all element content values in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I have this an ArrayController with some elements in it. I display a property "content" of the elements in a list with Handlebars like this:

```
{{#each}}
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <li>{{content}}</li>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

As noted in the template, I also make this editable (I have integrated the inline CKEditor) and I can edit these list items when I load the app.

The problem is that the changed data is not reflected back to the element object of the ArrayController, so that after I call save on the model, the "content" property is back to its original value.

If I modify the data by the ember textfield view, everything works fine, so changes are stored back into the element.

```
{{#each}}
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <li>{{textarea value=content}}</li>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Is there a way to tell handlebars that all element values should be two-way bound to the properties?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind value to the content.
This should solve your problem

```
<textarea {{bind-attr value=content}} />

// or

{{view Ember.TextArea value=content}}
```

Comment: Hi saygunicyuz, thanks for the answer... but I do not want to use TextField view, I would like to bind _any_ content of html. As far as I can tell there is no big difference between your example and (the working) version with textarea, except for using textfield instead of textarea...

Answer (score 0):

The CKEditor must create a 'textarea' when you add 'contenteditable="true"'

This textarea is not bound to Ember controller.

So you can do :
   1) get the value from CKeditor in the 'save' action.
 or
   2) Change CKeditor to make it Ember compatible.